# What is jqueryUI trying to represent with their new search icon?

Tags: icons, css, jquery

JqueryUI seems to have a new site design. They seem to have opted for unusual icon for their search box.

[image: New search icon on JqueryUI page]

Viewing the source yeilds:

/*  Font Awesome uses the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA) to ensure screen
    readers do not read off random characters that represent icons */
.icon-glass:before                { content: "\f000"; }
.icon-music:before                { content: "\f001"; }
.icon-search:before               { content: "\f002"; }

Looking closer at the font file it does seem a little bizarre.

[image: The letter O seems a little malformed]

Any idea what they are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the icon they're referencing with content: "\f002" is intended to be a normal magnifying glass, per the FontAwesome docs: http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#icon/icon-search

The FontAwesome site shows a blank spot in the WOFF file that loads:

[image: fontawesome-webfont.woff from fontawesome.github.com]